# Two div's, one slideshow, css

Tags: html, css

Hi i'm trying to take one slideshow that was orginaly in one div and place it into two div's having a thumbnail hover image on the left and the "output" image on the right but it just refuses to work right and my css knowledge mostly comes down to tinkering with the "code".

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQbK4/3/)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Blockrim Realms</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
font-size: 40pt;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Begin Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Begin Header -->
<div id="header">
<div id="backgroundimg"></div><div id="htext">Blockrim Realms</div></div>
<!-- End Header -->
<!-- Begin Navigation -->
<div id="navigation" class="auto-style1"> <strong>Blockrim Realms</strong></div>
<!-- End Navigation -->
<div id="leftcolumn">  Featured Screenshots!<br />
    <br />
    <a href="#">
        <img class="thumb" alt="" src="images/centralstation.png" />
    </a><br />&nbsp;Central Station<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="#">
        <img class="thumb" alt=""src="images/hydlaaplaza.png" />
        <img class="big" alt=""src="images/hydlaaplaza.png" />
    </a><br />&nbsp;Hydlaa Plaza<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="#">
        <img class="thumb" alt=""src="images/islesofteleport.png" />
        <img class="big" alt=""src="images/islesofteleport.png" />
    </a><br />&nbsp;Isles of Teleport<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="#">
        <img class="thumb" alt=""src="images/blackpearl.png" />
        <img class="big" alt=""src="images/blackpearl.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<!-- End Left Column -->
<!-- Begin Content Column -->
<!-- Begin Content Column -->
<div id="content">
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="big" alt=""src="images/centralstation.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="big featured" alt=""src="images/spawn.png" />
    </a>
&nbsp;<br />
&nbsp;The Black Pearl</div></div>
<!-- End Content Column -->
<!-- Begin Footer -->
<div id="footer"> </div>
<!-- End Footer -->
</div>
<!-- End Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
background-color:#272B30
}
#wrapper { 
margin: 0 auto;
width: 950px;
}
#header {
color: #fff;
width: 922px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
height: 40px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background:#3A3F44;
z-index:2;
}
#backgroundimg {
height: 40px;
width:100%;
background:url('images/grayradiant.jpg') center;
position:absolute;
left:0;
z-index:1;
}
#htext {
color: #BBBFC2;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:large;
position:absolute;
margin-top: 10px;
z-index:3;
}
#navigation {
float: left;
width: 922px;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background-color:#202328;
}
#leftcolumn { 
color: #333;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background:#F6F0E0;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 10px;
height: 600px;
width: 300px;
float: left;
}
#content { 
float: left;
color: #fff;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
border-top: 0px solid #000;
background:#202328;
margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
padding: 10px;
height: 600px;
width: 922px;
display: inline;
}
#footer { 
width: 922px;
clear: both;
color: #fff;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
background-color:#202328;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 10px;
}
/*SLIDER*/
.container {
position: relative;
height: 500px;
width: 922px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.big {
position: absolute;
top:1000px;
left:260px;
width:640px;
z-index: 2;

-webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
-moz-transition: top 1s ease;
-o-transition: top 1s ease;
-ms-transition: top 1s ease;
transition: top 1s ease;
}
a {
float: left;
margin: 0px;
}
a:hover .thumb {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.thumb{
width:100px;
margin-left:20px;
}
a:hover .big {
top: 0px;
width:640px;
}
.featured {
width:640px;
top: 0px;
left: 260px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: can you post the link to your JsFiddle? see here and post: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LQbK4/1/ guess that's it but i've never used this thing before.

Comment: ohh without the images it's hard undestand something. please reduce dimensions of the images just for try.

Comment: this thing doesn't even properly display how it's supposed to look but eh... here's with the changed thumbnail size

Comment: i try to see it but i dont promise anything

Comment: oh i forgot to add, it's only the first image on the left that i've tried to change so far.

Comment: ok but sorry man with jquery you can do a slideshow you know? there are some libraries

Comment: i don't plant on using that and it seems i forgot to add the link http://jsfiddle.net/LQbK4/2/

Comment: but why? them are better and faster to use! have you tried one time?

Comment: nope, i'm just making a simple page but that slideshow bugs me, it works fine in 1 div but not in 2

Comment: how you want but them are very simple

Comment: I may have figured it out afterall, by moving the content of <div id="leftcolumn"> to under <div class="container"> where the rest of the slideshow is and it seems to work like i wanted it too after that.

Comment: yes i got it working.